# How to make arithmetic ops on elements of fetched from DB arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, date, html-table

I'm learning PHP and AJAX.

***My task:***

Working on calendar notifications. User enters an event date and 3 notifications (days before an event) before it.

***How I do:***

Write, update and store event date and three notifications (in the form of "days before" and calculated notifications dates in DB. See my table structure:
[image]

Here *"select1, select2, select3"* mean number of days before an event, *day_remind1, day_remind2, day_remind3* mean calculated and saved notification dates. How it looks:
[image]

User can change notifications dates, so I need to: create editable HTML table, which can calculate, change and immediately show data in second cell after user makes changes in the first cell.

***My variant:***

(To be short I show just the part of my project related to the problem):

1. **Days.php** which draws my HTML table:

   ```
   <?php
   function showImen() {

    global $pdo, $loged, $day_remind1_updated, $day_remind2_updated, 
    $day_remind3_updated;
    global $show, $id, $value, $k;

    if (!empty($loged)) {
     $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM day_table WHERE login=?");
     $stmt2->execute([$loged]);
     $show = $stmt2->fetchAll();
    }
   } 
   ?>

   <tbody>
   <?php
   foreach($show as $k=>$value) {     
      $name = $value['name']);
      $surname = $value['surname']);
   ?>
   <div id="birthday-data">
    <tr class="table-row">
     <td aria-label="Name"> <?php echo $name;?></td>
     <td aria-label="Surname"><?php echo $surname;?></td>
     <td aria-label="Event date"><?php echo $value['birthday']; ?></td>

     <td aria-label="First notification" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'select1','<?php echo $show[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $show[$k]["select1"]; ?></td>
     <td id="one"><?php echo $value['day_remind1']; ?></td>
     <td aria-label="Second notification" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'select2','<?php echo $show[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $show[$k]["select2"]; ?></td>
     <td id="two"><?php echo $value['day_remind2']; ?></td>
     <td aria-label="Third notification" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'select3','<?php echo $show[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $show[$k]["select3"]; ?></td>
     <td id="three"><?php echo $value['day_remind3']; ?></td>
     <td align='center'>
        <span class='delete' id='del_<?php echo $show[$k]["id"]; ?>'><img id="delete_img" src="/download/a/img/delete_icon.png"></span>
     </td>
   </tr>
   ```
2. **Count.php (controller)** which makes calculations:

   ```
     function countDaysNewData() {
      global $pdo, $loged;

      if (!empty($loged)) { 

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT select1, select2, select3, birthday 
           FROM day_table WHERE login=?");
        $stmt->execute([$loged]);
        $res = $stmt->fetchAll();

         foreach ($res as $k => $value) {
           $arr = strtotime($res[0]['birthday']) - ($res[0]['select1'] * 86400); //0 element of 'select1' column
           $arr_to_date = date('Y-m-d', $arr);

           $arr2 = strtotime($res[0]['birthday']) - ($res[0]['select2'] * 86400); //0 element of 'select2' column
           $arr2_to_date = date('Y-m-d', $arr2);

           $arr3 = strtotime($res[0]['birthday']) - ($res[0]['select3'] * 86400); //0 element of 'select3' column
           $arr3_to_date = date('Y-m-d', $arr3);

           /* .. and so one. If user entered 3 events with 3 notification in 
           each of them, 
           here must be 9 manually written lines of 
           code with same substarction ops - it is very unuseful of course, 
           and that's the question */

           }
        }
        echo $arr_to_date;
        echo $arr2_to_date;
        echo $arr3_to_date;
        ?>
   ```
3. **Show.php (view)** which shows calculated dates:

   ```
   <?php
    require_once 'count.php';
    countDaysNewData();
   ?>
   ```

***My question:***
My variant works, but only if number of elements in arrays is constant and little. This approach is not optimal and wrong if (as in my task) user can enter more and more elements in DB columns.

What should I do to first loop over DB to fetch 4 columns in 4 arrays, then loop over each array and at the same time make atithmetic substract operations on their elements and save results?

Comment: You have a `foreach` loop, but then you're not using the values created by each loop.  If you used the loop values instead of `$res[0]`, then you wouldn't need "9 manually written lines of code"

Comment: What you want to achieve would be best accomplished with JavaScript - and even better with a reactive framework, e.g. Vue.

Comment: @PatrickQ, sorry, didn't understand the idea. Could you please give an example of suitable use of loop values?

Comment: You have this loop: `foreach ($res as $k => $value) {`.  Why aren't you actually making use of these?  You know what this loop is doing, right?  The whole point of a loop is so that you _don't_ have to write the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In programming, a loop repeatedly executes the same thing. In your case you are using a loop to handle data from records:

```
  foreach ($res as $k => $value) {
    $arr = strtotime($res[0]['birthday']) - ($res[0]['select1'] * 86400); //0 element of 'select1' column
    $arr_to_date = date('Y-m-d', $arr);

    $arr2 = strtotime($res[0]['birthday']) - ($res[0]['select2'] * 86400); //0 element of 'select2' column
    $arr2_to_date = date('Y-m-d', $arr2);

    $arr3 = strtotime($res[0]['birthday']) - ($res[0]['select3'] * 86400); //0 element of 'select3' column
    $arr3_to_date = date('Y-m-d', $arr3);

    }
 }
```

Let's recognize the pattern here. You will need two lines into each iteration. You are using $res[0] everywhere and birthday. The thing you change here is the number at the end of select, like select1, select2, ...

and you convert all of them into time and then into `date`. Let's make our loop useful:

```
$index = 1;
$dateArray = array();
while (isset($res[0][$key = 'select'.$index])) {
    $dateArray[($index++)] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($res[0]['birthday']) - ($res[0][$key] * 86400));
}
```

and now you have a `$dateArray`, which can be looped on its own:

```
foreach ($dateArray as $index => $value) {
    //$index is the number and $value is the date
}
```

Your database is not in an ideal format, you might want to read about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to improve your schema.

Comment: Thank you for a good and detailed answer. Don't know why, but having troubles with `while` loop. Server pending to refresh page, answer with 504 error.. What am I doing wrong? (Just copied your code and echoed an array..)

Comment: @aysee that was my mistake. Forgot to increment $index in each iteration. I have edited my answer to fix this, changed (isset($res[0][$key = 'select'.$index])) to (isset($res[0][$key = 'select'.($index++)])) in order to increment $index in each iteration. $index++ returns $index's old value and increments it, so its old value will be higher in the next iteration.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much!

Comment: @aysee I have made a further fix in the code since your last comment, please use the new code. $index should be incremented after its last use of the cycle.

Comment: Good day! Trying to modify your code to my case. In its original form it allows fetching data from just 1st row (because of res[0] index i suppose). So I try to rewrite cycle in this form: `while (isset($res[$index++][$key = 'select'.$index])) {
       $dateArray[($index++)] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($res[$index++]['birthday']) - ($res[$index++][$key] * 86400));` , waitning script will loop over res[0] , res [1] etc...but unfrortunately it's not right. Can you comment, please, what approach should I use to solve my problem?

Comment: @aysee you did not specify how is this not working, but try to use index++ at its last occurrence in the while, because currently in each iteration you are increasing index with 4, which is probably not what you wanted to achieve.